# Find the value of $2p+4q+7r$ given that $2p,\ q,\ 2r$ are in geometric progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics

It is given that $2p,\ q, \ 2r$ are in G.P.

Also the roots of the quadratic equation
$$px^2+qx+r=0$$ are of the form $\alpha ^2,\ 4\alpha -4$.

Find the value of $2p+4q+7r$.

From the given data:
Following conclusions can be drawn 
$$q^2=4pr\ \implies q^2-4pr=0$$

Therefore the given quadratic equation has equal roots.
 Which gives $$\alpha ^2-4\alpha +4=0$$ i.e. $\alpha=2$

So, we have $$4p+2q+r=0$$.

How do I proceed?

Comment: $x = \alpha^2 \Rightarrow 16p+4q+r=0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has infinitely many solutions.

As $2p,q$ and $2r$ are in geometric progression, there exists a constant $k$ such that $2pk = q$ and $qk = 2r$.

The discriminant in quadratic equation is $$\Delta = q^2-4pr = q^2-4\frac{q}{2k}\frac{qk}{2}=0.$$ Thus, $x = -\frac{q}{2p} = -k$ is the only solution.

Hence, $\alpha^2 = -k$ and $4\alpha-4=-k \Rightarrow k = -4.$

Thus,
$p = -\frac{q}{8}$ and $r = -2q$, vanishing the expression $16p+4q+r$, obtained from the quadratic equation.

Examples:

If $p = -1,q = 8$ and $r = -16$, the sum $2p+4q+7r = -82.$ However,  If $p = 2,q = -16$ and $r = 32$, the sum $2p+4q+7r = 164.$

Comment: The original problem was a multiple choice question, and the options were $0,\ 10,\ 14, \18$. The answer is 14. How possibly could the other values be rejected?

Comment: @Shubham as stated, any non zero real number is a solution. Did your original question (you should've reproduced that) mention anything else - for e.g. That $p,q,r$ are integers? Then you get $14$ as the only choice among that list.

Comment: Maybe the author forgot to mention that. Now, supposing they were integers,  how do we reject others

Comment: @Macavity, the examples that I have presented are integer solutions.

Comment: @Shubham, Could you  tell me the author's name and the book?

Comment: @Alex , It' s not some very popular book or famous author, and this was the first edition.

Comment: Missed your comments. If integers, $(p,q,r) \propto (1, -8, 16) \implies 2p+4q+7r=82n$ for any integer $n$. Looks likely "the question" is just incorrect or at best incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you have found a quadratic equation with roots $\alpha$, so what could $p,q,r$ be (upto a constant of proportionality)?